# using checkboxes echoing the value of checkbox when checked

Tags: php, html, arrays, post, checkbox

I have a,b,c in a table with check boxes I want by clicking sub button echoing value of  checkboxes that are checked

```
<?php
 $array=array('a','b','c');
 echo "<table border=2>";
     for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
     {
     echo "<tr>
     <td><input type='Checkbox' name='p[$i]'  value='$array[$i]' unchecked />
     <td>$array[$i]</td>
     </tr>";
     }
    echo "</table>";
if(array_key_exists('sub',$_POST))
        if(isset($_POST['p']))
         {
         foreach($_POST['p'] as $key=>$value)
             //I have problem here;
   }
?> 
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta content="">
</head>
<body>
<form method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='sub' value='echome'>
</body>
</html>
```

I have problem in echoing and if(isset($_POST['p'])) is not working
what I must do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the `table` containing `checkboxes` is echo'ed outside the `form` tag, which is why 'p' is not submitted with form post and `$_POST['p']` is not found by PHP. Move your PHP code right after the `form` tag is created in HTML.

Comment: You are right! thank you very much now it works:D I echoed this:`echo $_POST['p'][$key];`